# How to configure gcsfuse to mount a bucket in a google cloud vm and access the resources in the best way?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

When gcsfuse is used to mount a bucket in a google cloud vm and we access that resource, for example an image through a url that was configured for the vm, example.com/image.jpg, is internal traffic created between the vm instance and the bucket mounted with gcsfuse ?, the response time for the image is affected ?, Would it be better to call it from the bucket for example https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/imagen.jpg ?, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that gcsfuse is simply an API wrapper that transform os read/write calls into API gRPC calls.

Thus, all the stuff around the GCS API calls are applied:

- Latency
- Inter-region network traffic (if applicable, for example is your bucket is in multiregional class)
- [Per request and per operation type billing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing)

I'm not sure that calling the file directly like this `https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/imagen.jpg` is more efficient. A new HTTP call is initiated (with SSL handshake and so on). I never tested but I have the feeling that with gcsfuse it can be more efficient.